# Best practices for integrating two systems via a web-service

Tags: web-services, integration

In my case the separate system is a web-service (but it could conceivably be anything).
My question is what are the best practices when you integrate against a separate system such as a web-service when it comes to data?

Example: Web-service provides a list of products. Products are grouped using categories. You can get all products in a sub-category. You can get a specific product by its id (an integer) or its name (a unique value).

In my application:

I display the list of categories and products - and the user can choose the product and specify an order quantity.

1. Should I store the name of the category or the id of the category?
2. Should I store the name of the product or the id of the product?
3. How should I name the field in the database that stores the data from the web-service
   (CategoryId or WsCategoryId: so that by convention one knows where the value is coming from?)

Any other best practices?

Any other references?

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understand that the web service's interface looks something like this:

```
/product/
/product/{ProductId}
/product/{ProductName}
/product/category/{CategoryId}
```

Since you are asking if you should store `CategoryName`, I assume that it is unique (same as `ProductName`).
I also assume that the web service handles cases where products or categories are renamed transparently (i.e. by providing a redirect or any other means which allow you to detect this and handle it accordingly). If it doesn't, do not consider storing names as references to products or categories - always use IDs.

I would provide the same answer to your **questions #1 and #2**. Even though uniqueness of `ProductName` and `CategoryName` will technically allow you to store them in your application as unique identifiers of products and categories, I would opt for storing their IDs instead. The main decision point would be your storage medium. Since you are using a database, and the web service allows you to access objects by unique numerical IDs, database normalization rules should apply - hence you should **store IDs**.

The above however assumes that you are using a relational database - if you are using a NoSQL database, I assume that storing names instead of IDs would be a viable option as well (at least as far as I can tell with my current understanding of NoSQL solutions, unfortunately I don't have any practical experience with any of them yet).

Regarding **question #3** - I would stick with the naming conventions that you already use in your database. There are many different conventions for naming tables and columns out there, so I really doubt that there are any standardized conventions on how to name columns referencing web service objects. I would name them according to your **existing naming conventions** and in a way that **purpose of the columns is clear** to everybody who is using the system. Note that if there is a chance that you will be using other web services in the future, you should consider keeping the name of the service in the column name rather than using a generic `ws` prefix - e.g. `AmazonProductId` or `AmazonCategoryId`.

I'll try to point out a few items from my experience, but I would not label them as **best practices** - just topics to think about.

In my experience, I found it useful to treat data from web services in the same fashion as the data from a database - at least from an application's perspective, where your storage layer would be abstracted from application logic. By this I mean that you would should think about and prepare for similar scenarios regardless if your storage medium is a database or a web service. **Same as databases, web services can go down, both can have their data or integrity corrupt, both will require you to sanitize or otherwise process data on input.**

**Caching of data** should be an item which is high on your list - apart from the obvious performance reasons, it can allow you to deal with outages of the web service (to an extend limited by which data you cache).
An example would be that your application displays a list products most frequently purchased products in your application. If your application stores only IDs of products, you will have to do one or more requests to the web service in order to retrieve the names of all products which you need to display in the list. If you cache product names locally or in your database, you will achieve better performance, conserve your resources and you will also have a failsafe scenario in case that the web service goes down.

**Referential integrity** is one other important aspect to think about when working with web services. As the web service is completely separate from your database, you do not have the option to create foreign keys as you would do in a database-only solution. This means that data changes in the web service (i.e. product updates or deletions) can break the integrity of data in your database.

Regarding **references**, these depend mostly on the type of web service that you are about to use (you didn't specify which service you will be using). If the service is based on REST principles, I can recommend [Restful Web Services by Leonard Richardson and Sam Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260). Even though it isn't focused on application/service integration as such, it's a great introduction into REST.